# PySpark DataFrame Converting Row values into column names

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a Pyspark dataframe in the below format:

[image]

And I need to convert it into something like this:

[image]

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new column `row_num` using `row_number` and then use `pivot`. See below logic for details -

**Input Data**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = [("Name", "ABC"),
                                   ("Number", "889"),
                                   ("Zip", "99882"),
                                   ("Name", "DEF"), 
                                   ("Number", "998"),
                                   ("Zip", "99880")],
                           schema = ["Header", "Value"]
                          )
df.show()

+------+-----+
|Header|Value|
+------+-----+
|  Name|  ABC|
|Number|  889|
|   Zip|99882|
|  Name|  DEF|
|Number|  998|
|   Zip|99880|
+------+-----+
```

Now create a new column as `row_num` using `row_number` function.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Window

df1 = df.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("Header").orderBy("Value")))
```

Finally, `groupBy` this newly created column and use `pivot` on `Header` column.

```
df1.groupBy("row_num").pivot("Header").agg(first("Value")).drop("row_num").show()

+----+------+-----+
|Name|Number|  Zip|
+----+------+-----+
| ABC|   889|99880|
| DEF|   998|99882|
+----+------+-----+
```